# Sql query problem while joining the query to another query

Tags: sql-server

I am running the below query in sql but it is giving the below error.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What I have tried :

```sql
SELECT b.Service_Name,
       c.Service_Type,
       Application_No,
       Reg_No,
       Student_Name,
       (SELECT CONVERT(char(10),
                       dt + (SELECT COUNT(1)
                             FROM Holiday_list
                             WHERE Date_Fmt BETWEEN School_update AND dt),
                       103) AS cnt
        FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN Service_TypeID = '1' THEN (School_update + 30) ELSE (School_update + 5) END AS dt
              FROM Application_Status) a ) AS Nxt_date,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, School_update, GETDATE()) AS Day_Count,
       Created_Date,
       School_Code,
       CASE WHEN Payment_Status = 'Y' THEN 'PAID' WHEN Payment_Status = 'N' THEN 'NOT PAID' END AS Payment_Status
FROM Application_Status a,
     MST_Service b,
     MST_ServiceType c,
     KSEEBMASTERS.dbo.MST_SCHOOL s,
     MST_Division d
WHERE a.Service_ID = b.Service_ID
  AND s.SCM_SCHOOL_CODE COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = a.School_Code
  AND s.DIST_CODE COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = d.DistrictCode
  AND a.Service_TypeID = c.Type_ID
  AND d.DivisionCode = 'ED'
  AND Payment_Status = 'Y'
  AND school_status = 'Y'
  AND Div_Status = 'N';
```

But the problem is in the below query while joining the query to another query.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(char(10),
               dt + (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM Holiday_list
                     WHERE Date_Fmt BETWEEN School_update AND dt),
               103) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN Service_TypeID = '1' THEN (School_update + 30) ELSE (School_update + 5) END AS dt,
             School_update
      FROM Application_Status) a;
```

Here Application_Status is sone table with Column name School_Update and Holiday_List is another table with column name Date_Fmt.

Comment: The error is literally telling you the problem here; you have a subquery that is returning 2 (or more) values and it isn't allowed to. Also, *please* get in the habit making **good** use of line breaks and whitespace when writing. That Code is impossible to easily read. I have formatted it for you, for the s̶a̶n̶i̶t̶y̶  benefit of other users here. Also, it's 2020; you've had 28 years to adopt the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax now, please do start using that as well. Finally, `MST_Service` doesn't have a single `b` in it, nor a `c`. Use appropriate aliases for your objects.

Comment: Some recommended (required) reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) & [Fundamentals: White space and Line Breaks](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-white-space-and-line-breaks/)

Comment: Thank you so much sir, as I am new and learning lot of the things.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message: if you nest a query to get a field, that query must return one and only one row.
So your issue is there in the last query that you posted, but not in nested query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Holiday_list (...)` because it's an aggregate query.
Maybe it's just that `SELECT CASE WHEN Service_TypeID = '1' THEN (School_update + 30) ELSE (School_update + 5) END AS dt, School_update FROM Application_Status` returns more then one row and therefore also the query that contains it.